What is the difference between `expect(locator).toBeVisible()` and `locator.waitFor()` in Playwright?
I have seen examples of using await locator.waitFor(), to assert whether an element is visible on the page. I would like to know if it should be used this way.
await locator.waitFor()

await expect(locator).toBeVisible();

Both methods work very similarly, but can they be used alternately? What might be the consequences of using await locator.waitFor() as an assertion? What is the difference between these two methods?

Did you check the docs? https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for. There are various options you can pass to waitFor, so it's a superset of toBeVisible, but the default state is 'visible', meaning they're basically the same except for different assertion failure output and syntax.
